# Text to binary conversion and writing to file. help please

Tags: java, file, binary

I'm trying to convert plain text data to binary format so that it becomes non-redable.
The data needs to be written to a file. The conversion works if I print it in console window, and cannot read original text.
However, when it is written to a file, the same original text appears.
How can I write this binary data to a file, without encrypting it, but making it non-readable?

This file, later needs to be processed by another third party tool which accepts binary data. This is why I cannot encrypt it using my own algo.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class convert{
public static void main( String args[] ){
String s= "This is text";
try{
File file= new File("test.php");
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter( file.getName(), true );
BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter( fw );

byte[] b= s.getBytes();
for(int x=0; x<b.length; x++){
byte c=b[x];
bw.write( c );
System.out.println(c);
}

bw.close();
}catch( Exception e ){ e.printStackTrace(); }
}//main
}//class
```

Comment: There is probably a better solution, but try using `bw.write(Byte.toString(c));` instead `bw.write( c );`

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense.  If you don't intend to encrypt your file, how do you purport to make it a binary file?  All you're doing right now is converting the string to a UTF-8 byte array, then converting the bytes to characters (a bad idea) and writing them out.  What format does this third-party tool expect?

Comment: Why don't you use BinaryWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain text is in itself a binary format, where each byte is interpreted as a character (or other variants, depending on assumed or specified encoding, e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16...).

This means that if you write an ASCII character as a byte to a file, it will look identical and will be readable by anyone. In fact, a lot of binary file formats still save strings as normal bytes, which means they can be read when opened in a hex editor, such as here:
[image: hex editor]

What you will need to do to make it unreadable is to serialize it into some common format that is not readable. Normal serialization in Java is unfortunately readable, but you can check [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things1/index.html#N101BB) for advice on how to obscure it. You can also use ZIP or similar compression algorithms as well.

Another, more hacky way, is to shift all your character bytes by some known value. This will result in them becoming a different character and it will be unreadable. This can be seen as a very basic [Caesar Chipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

But in the end, all that matters is which formats your target program is able to read.

Comment: ThankYou for all comments and answers. I'll try the suggestions and post then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a RandomAccessFile for this. It becomes easy.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path,permissions); //permissions are r,w,rw. The usual ones.
raf.seek(0); //this will set the pointer to first position.
raf.writeUTF(what ever you want to write to file);

//to read the file use readUTF()
raf.seek(0); //you can read from a part of file using this seek method.
System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
```